# Zend Framework advanced WHERE IN query

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table

So, i've come up with this query wich works perfectly fine when executed. However, since I want to use the pagination from Zend, the query has to be through an adapter.

This is the query that has to be converted: (i've cut the query so only the important part is here. I am aware of the fact that you can't run this query LOL)

```
//snip
WHERE
    city IN (
        SELECT 
            Plaatsnaam
        FROM
            plaatsnamen
        WHERE
            Latitude 
                BETWEEN 
                    ?
                AND 
                    ?
        AND
            Longitude
                BETWEEN
                    ?
                AND
                    ?       
    )
//snip
```

Works perfectly fine! However.. As you can see, i'm using an "advanced" WHERE IN case. Somehow, i can't get this converted and i'm stuck.

This is what it has to be converted to:

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();                
$select = $db->select('gethousecity.id, city')
                                ->from('gethousecity')
                                    ->join('houses_props', 'houses_props.id = gethousecity.id')
                                ->where('city IN ()') // HOW TO CONVERT THE UPPER QUERY TO FIT IT HERE?
                                ->where('is_online = 1')
                                ->where('houses_props.prop_name = ?', 'something')
                                ->where('houses_props.prop_value BETWEEN ? AND ?', array(1,2));
```

I haven't found any documentation at all on how to convert the query into some format that fits here. Does anyone have any idea? Mostly because I need to insert some values and ZF is rewriting some weird shit there.

I'm kinda stuck now, any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subqueries work just fine.

```
$select1->cols('id')->where('date > NOW()');
$select2->where('id IN (?)', $select1);
```

If the problem is the complex where, than you can use named parameters.

```
$select1 = $db->select();
$select2 = $db->select();
$select1->from('plaatsnamen', array('Plaatsnaam'))
        ->where('Latitude BETWEEN :latmin AND :latmax')
        ->where('Longitude BETWEEN :longmin AND :longmax');
$select2->from('gethousecity')
        ->join('houses_props', 'houses_props.id = gethousecity.id')
        ->where('city IN ?', $select1) // HOW TO CONVERT THE UPPER QUERY TO FIT IT HERE?
        ->where('is_online = 1')
        ->where('houses_props.prop_name = ?', 'something')
        ->where('houses_props.prop_value BETWEEN :propsmin AND :propsmax');
die($select2);
```

Returns:

```
SELECT `gethousecity`.*, `houses_props`.*
FROM `gethousecity`
INNER JOIN `houses_props` ON houses_props.id = gethousecity.id
WHERE 
    (city IN (
        SELECT `plaatsnamen`.`Plaatsnaam`
        FROM `plaatsnamen`
        WHERE 
        (Latitude BETWEEN :latmin AND :latmax) AND
        (Longitude BETWEEN :longmin AND :longmax)
    )) AND
    (is_online = 1) AND
    (houses_props.prop_name = 'something') AND
    (houses_props.prop_value BETWEEN :propsmin AND :propsmax)
```

Which should work with named parameters, as seen in [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.statement.html#zend.db.statement.executing)

```
$bind = array(
    ':latmin' => 10,
    ':latmax' => 3,
    '...' => '...',
);
$db->fetchAll($select2, $bind);
```

Comment: Yes, for those simple matters is does. Not when you have a subquery.

Comment: Yeah, that works as well! That's the weird thing, it works for named parameters. I'm upvoting your answer since you make use of the $db. In the end, both of our answers are correct!

Comment: But the main problem were the named parameters? You can easily create your own Db adapter and override the select. We use it to inject language suffixes to table cols - i.e.: change every {anything}_en to {anything}_de for user with german language.

Comment: You can also bind named parameters during creating select: `$select->bind(array(':latin' => 10, ':latex' => 3));`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, ZF DB does not have native support for subqueries.

You could try to do this:

```
// snip
->where("city IN (
    SELECT Plaatsnaam
    FROM plaatsnamen
    WHERE Latitude BETWEEN $lowLat AND $highLat
      AND Longitude BETWEEN $lowLon AND $highLon
)")
// snip
```

**EDIT**: Interpolating the values directly into the condition string, this is safe only if the variables are trusted (or if you got them from the user, make sure you cast them to floats before doing this).

Alternatively, you could try to avoid the subquery, and instead do a join but this may have performance implications (maybe for the better or worse).

Comment: Well, i've thought of that as well. However, it doesn't work. ZF rewrites the query in such a weird way: http://pastebin.com/veCSzj6A

Comment: @SiteSafeNL Can you post the resultant query?

Comment: The 4 values are pasted at once, in stead of one by one.. It doesn't make any sense to me

Comment: I just looked through the Zend_Db_Select code and the where() function only takes a single parameter, i.e. every ? in the clause gets quoted with the same value. 
The other option is to quote the values directly into the clause. Updating my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Indeed, and that's a design fault in my honest opinion :/

Comment: It's a design choice, I guess it helps when you have a bunch of ID's you want to include and can just do `->where('id IN (?)', $arrayOfIds)` but it could be smarter. Another thing you could have done is used named parameters.

Comment: Named parameters is also a good solution. A small note on your edit though; i've checked my parameters very well. Normally, you should escape any data you enter in your query to avoid SQL-injection. Just in case ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the end, as a quick workaround, i came up with the following; $db->quote.

```
$select = $db->select('gethousecity.id, city')
                                    ->from('gethousecity')
                                        ->join('houses_props', 'houses_props.id = gethousecity.id')
                                    ->where('city IN (  
                                                    SELECT Plaatsnaam
                                                    FROM plaatsnamen
                                                    WHERE Latitude BETWEEN '.$latlon_search[0].' AND '.$latlon_search[1].'
                                                        AND Longitude BETWEEN '.$latlon_search[2].' AND '.$latlon_search[3].'
                                    )') 
                                    ->where('is_online = 1')
                                    ->where('houses_props.prop_name = ?', 'vraagprijs[vraagprijs]')
                                    ->where('houses_props.prop_value BETWEEN '.$db->quote($price_start).' AND '.$db->quote($price_end));
```

For me, it was the only way to make this work. Every time i did:

```
->where('statement ? AND ?', array($val1, $val2)
```

The result was this:

```
statement val1,val2 AND val1,val2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();  
    $selectInner = $db->select()->from('plaatsnamen','Plaatsnaam')
                   ->where("Lattitude BETWEEN $lowLat AND $highLat")
                   ->where("Longitude BETWEEN $lowLon AND $highLon")
                   ->__toString();



    $select = $db->select('gethousecity.id, city')
                                    ->from('gethousecity')
                                        ->join('houses_props', 'houses_props.id = gethousecity.id')
                                    ->where("city IN ($selectInner)");
```

Comment: You should definitly quote the vars for safety matters.